# Find a specific tuple element in a vector of tuples?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, tuples

I am having an issue with finding a tuple element, in a vector of tuples.

I have a `vector<tuple<int,int,int,int>>` in which I need to find the position in the vector where `get<0>(vector) = 0`.  I need the position, as I need to extract the other values from the tuple in that position as well.

The value of `get<0>` is unique and will only occur once in the vector.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the `std::find_if` algorithm;

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int,int>> v =
    {{0,1,2,3},{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5}};

auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::tuple<int,int,int,int>& e) {return std::get<0>(e) == 0;});
if (it != v.end()) {
  std::cout << "Found" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is it the position it provides me or?, since you use auto ?

Comment: `it` is an iterator, it either points to the found value or `v.end()` if not found, hence the test `if (it != v.end())`.

Comment: @Lamda As a general advise, if you are unsure what the actual type is when using auto, lookout for the context. Here, I am comparing it against 'v.end()', so it has to be an iterator. If still unsure, check the signature of the function :). I hear such complaint about auto making code unclear all the time, but if you know the context, it's not that bad :)

Comment: What is the easiest way to find the last occurence of a given value in a vector of tuples? I tried to change v.begin() and v.end() to v.begin() and c.end() but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) algorithm to loop over the elements and test for the condition you require.

*Note*; the code here assumes you want to find the element in the vector where the first element of the tuple is 0.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<tuple<int, int, int, int>> v;
    v.emplace_back(0,1,2,3);
    auto it = find_if(begin(v), end(v), [](decltype(*begin(v)) e) {
        return get<0>(e) == 0;
    });
    if (it != end(v))
        cout << get<0>(*it) << " " << get<1>(*it);
}
```

`std::find_if` above uses the form that accepts a predicate;

> ```
> template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
>   InputIt find_if( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
> ```

And it returns;

> Returns [an iterator to] the first element in the range `[first, last)` that satisfies specific criteria...

---

A more terse syntax that can be used, but requires language support for C++14 onwards, is;

```
find_if(begin(v), end(v), [](auto&& e) { return get<0>(e) == 0; });
```

Comment: What is the easiest way to find the last occurence of a given value in a vector of tuples? I tried to change v.begin() and v.end() to v.begin() and c.end() but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Croppi. It’s sounds like you want to search in reverse order, try `rbegin()` and `rend()` in place of `begin()` and `end()`. Just swapping begin and end wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 5):

For C++14 and those that don't wish to torture their eyes.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

using std::get;
using std::tuple;
using std::vector;
using std::find_if;

int main( int, char** )
{
    int needle = 0;
    vector< tuple< int, int, int > > haystack;

    auto position = find_if( haystack.begin( ), haystack.end( ),
                             [ = ]( auto item )
                             {
                                 return get< 0 >( item ) == needle;
                             } );

    if ( position not_eq haystack.end( ) )
        haystack.erase( position );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```